# How to create a HTML template in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a long code. For example:

```
<% Post.limit(10).offset(10).order(id: :desc).each do |post| %>
    ######## FROM HERE ###########
    <% unless post.image.blank? %>
    <% img = post.image.split(' ') %>
    <% if post.post_type == 1 %>
        <div class="post_type1">
          <h1>
            <a href="post/<%= post.slug %>">
              <%= post.title %>
            </a>
          </h1>
       </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
    ####### TO HERE #########
<% end %>
```

So, I want to make this part(FROM HERE <-> TO HERE part) like a template. So I wrote first line, later `render or something else, I do not know` and the last line for displaying all the page. Can you help me with it?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're talking about. What is an "HTML template"? Are you trying to make a [partial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials)?

Comment: Yes. I want to create a partial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put it in a file (lets call it `_post.html.erb`) and include it like:

```
<% Post.limit(10).offset(10).order(id: :desc).each do |post| %>
  <%= render partial: 'post', locals: { post: post } %>
<% end %>
```

Note the use of `locals: { post: post }` that passes the variable `post` in your loop to your partial. Another thing to note is that your file name starts with an underscore (`_`) which is left out when you render the partial.

Read more about partials in [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials).

Comment: Must I put this _post file into views/posts/ folder?

Comment: It doesn't matter where you put it as long as you enter its path relative to `views/` folder.